# How Can/Do I [Know] Which IP Address I Want To Reference?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ip-address, router

I am not incredibly familiar with NAT / Port Forwarding - I get the concept, but still trying to understand the why of it all. Nonetheless, I am attempting to

1. Create a Website to get their public IP
2. Send that IP to another service
3. Have that service send that IP a request on a specific port

To my understanding, let's say there are 5 devices connected to a single router. When PC1 and PC2 try to ping Google - they both ping from an identical IP, however, a different port from a router. That port indicates to the router that I am requesting to send information to a specific device connected to that router.

**TLDR:**

How can I obtain a specific IP from a computer that I can use for a different service in the very near future?

**Current Attempts:**

I have created an AWS Lambda to obtain the Source IP:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    const ip = event["requestContext"]["identity"]["sourceIp"];
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(ip),
    };
    return response;
};
```

But, isn't this for EVERY device behind that router, if it is one? How do I know for sure that I am connecting to a specific device that is behind that router?

**Edit 1**:

My end-goal was to be able to create a remote connection using RFB provided the users IP Address. I assumed, I could easily be wrong, that I would be able to obtain their IP by having them access a public website that would provide it then I would be able to create that connection.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do or accomplish.  You cannot determine the actual private IP address of a client behind a NAT device.  That information is entirely hidden from you and it wouldn't do you any good any way because it's probably a non-routable IP address (e.g. a private IP address) that is only useful from on that local network.  You can capture the IP address of the gateway or NAT translator, but that by itself won't allow you to contact the original client as all that does is get you a connection to the gateway itself.

Comment: The source port number that comes with a request from a client behind a NAT device is only useful for that specific connection and helps the NAT device know how to route return packets sent back on that specific connection.  It's not generally useful over the long run for contacting the client on the private network.  Each time a client makes an outbound request through the gateway, it will probably have a different source port number (they are dynamically assigned).  And, the NAT device may even map the outbound port number too (changing it).

Comment: For UDP-based protocols, the NAT device will leave the outbound port open for some period of time to allow the original destination to send packets back to it for a little while and some P2P protocols use that feature in their communication mechanisms, but this is still temporary and not something you can save and use days later.

Comment: What is your step 3: "Have that service send that IP a request on a specific port" actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've added clarification

Comment: All you get when the user accesses a public website is the IP address of the gateway that their connection comes through (home router, university proxy, etc...).  And, as I already said, if you want to connect directly to the client, you can't do that from the outside even if you had the client IP address.  I don't know RFB, but you will likely need the client to connect to your server, not the other way around.

Comment: Interesting - So generally in RFB - the client IS the server - opens up their port 5900 (usually) and someone would connect to that port. Most VNC work that way - I just figured there was a less tech-savvy way to achieve this goal of having someone connect to them.

Comment: That would work on the private network where you aren't going through the internet gateway, but not from the internet.

Comment: I thought that as well - until https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Code.aspx does it. Was thoroughly surprised when a friend showed me this. Was trying to mimic that capability - figured it was simple.

Comment: I don't know how that site works, but if the connection initiates from in the private network out to something on the internet, then you can send data both ways over that connection.  The NAT/gateway will permit that, but not the other way around.  Or, there are some P2P tricks with UDP that can enable communication between two computers both behind NAT/firewalls.

Comment: Security Groups are stateful. They allow return traffic to come back from requests sent out. So, LogMeIn first send a request from the private network, which allows return traffic to come back. Same for services like Skype.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like I would have to create some sort of VM for pc1 to connect to and pc2 to connect to - then send the information between the 2 connections. Unless that is also wrong?